# Why is in_array() returning false always? php

Tags: php, forms

Still getting the hang of PHP here.  I've seen other questions similar to this but I can't figure out why mine is returning false.  I have a form that sends text and attaches files via email.  The form sends the files as expected but once I started trying to validate for filetype I started only getting the error.  Why is my validation always returning false?

```
$error = False;
$file_type = $_FILES['upload']['type']; //returns the mimetype

$allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif", "application/pdf");


$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$attachments = "None";
$attachmentString = "No Attachments";

if(isset($_FILES['upload']['name']) && is_array($_FILES['upload']['name']) && count($_FILES['upload']['name']) > 0){

    // Loop through each file
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
      //Get the temp file path
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

      //Make sure we have a filepath
      if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $uploaddir = trailingslashit( realpath(__DIR__) ) . 'uploads/';
        wp_mkdir_p( $uploaddir );
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i]);
        if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
            $error = True;
            echo "Error: Only jpg, gif, png, and pdf files are allowed.<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            //Upload the file into the temp dir
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
               $attachments[$i] = $newFilePath;
               //make string for mimetype headers in email
               $attachmentString += implode($attachments[$i]) + ", ";
            }
        }

   }
}
```

}

Comment: try to `var_dump($file_type)` and see if it's correct.

Comment: `$file_type` is __array__. And if you printed it out you would see it. But who does debugging today?

Comment: What does     echo $file_type   before the in_array give you? You also might need to add image/jpg to your file type array

Comment: it is.  I've even tried using in_array("image/png", $allowed); and am still getting false.  Clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: Don't take the value of `$_FILES['upload']['type']` for granted, in essence its browser generated data that does not have to exist and on top of that it can be manipulated, so your script is not really secure.

Comment: @Xorifelse thanks for the tip. I want to make it more secure.  If I am clearing the upload folder after the form is submitted to email, does that cover my bases for malicious file uploads?

Comment: Nope, it does not. Check out my file name: `../../../etc/passwd`, now move it to the directory. Perhaps read [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you update multiple files in PHP, the `mimetype` of each files gets into the `$_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i]` variable.

In your code, you check if the value of `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` (which is array) exists in the `$allowed` types (and this is always false).

You can change your code to:

```
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
    ....
    $file_type = $_FILES['upload']['type'][$i]; //returns the mimetype
    ....
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
        $error = True;
        echo "Error: Only jpg, gif, png, and pdf files are allowed.<br />";
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!